# Trying to fix the scale of a game object in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script that faces my player (cube) to its moving direction. It also has a grappling gun, but when he turns to its moving direction, gun turns too and it can't use grappling gun when i try to grapple and object staying on the opposite site of my player.

This is how i turn my player:

```
private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && HorizontalInput() < 0f || !isFacingRight && HorizontalInput() > 0f)
        {
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
```

If I can fix the localScale of my gun, so that it won't multiplied with -1 when i multiply the whole body.

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question: you want to flip the player but not flip the gun (which is a child of the player).

One way of doing this is to organize the Player object like this:
-Player (prefeb, invisible)
--PlayerGraphicChild (Cube, flip this one only)
--PlayerGunChild (don't flip this one).

Another way is to add a new prefeb called Gun, and set the position of that object to one of the children of Player. Organize the hierarchy like this:
-Player (flip this one)
--PlayerGunDolly (flips with parent)
and create a new prefeb:
-Gun (has a component that sets the transform.position to transform of PlayerGunDolly. Does not flip.)